# Is there a way to conditionally set the type of a public data structure?

Tags: fortran

Is there a way to conditionally set a public data structure?

For example:

```
MODULE EXAMPLE

  USE DATA_TYPE_Define, ONLY: DATA_TYPE_A, DATA_TYPE_B
  USE PARAMETER,        ONLY: CaseAisTrue

  ! Disable all implicit typing
  IMPLICIT NONE

  ! ------------
  ! Visibilities
  ! ------------
  ! Everything private by default
  PRIVATE
  ! The shared data
  PUBLIC :: DATA

  ! ------------------------------------------------
  ! The shared data 
  ! ------------------------------------------------

  IF (CaseAisTrue) Then
     TYPE(DATA_TYPE_A), SAVE :: DATA
  ELSE
     TYPE(DATA_TYPE_B), SAVE :: DATA
  END IF


CONTAINS
  ...
```

Where DATA_TYPE_A and DATA_TYPE_B are two different data structures/derived types.

Is there any good way to set this up besides introducing more public variables?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you would like the variable `Data` to be of either `data_type_a` or `data_type_b` depending on some run time condition?

Comment: If it is really a constant, consider preprocessing.

Comment: Thank you both for helping clarify my questions; yes, Data needs to be able to change on certain run-time conditions. Option 1 in the below answer seems suitable for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options.

1. Can this change at runtime? Then, the only reason you may need to access the same `DATA` anywhere else in the code later is because `DATA_TYPE_A` and `DATA_TYPE_B` have essentially the same API. This is a typical example object-oriented programming pattern: you want the two data types share the same API:

```
! The base class
type, abstract, public :: DATA_TYPE
end type DATA_TYPE

type, public, extends(DATA_TYPE) :: DATA_TYPE_A
   [...]
end type DATA_TYPE_A

type, public, extends(DATA_TYPE) :: DATA_TYPE_B
   [...]
end type DATA_TYPE_B
```

If you need to keep switching between the data types you're accessing, you can have two separate variables for them:

```
! Actual shared data, here or elsewhere
type(DATA_TYPE_A), target, SAVE :: DATA_A
type(DATA_TYPE_B), target, SAVE :: DATA_B
```

And point to them using a pointer:

```
class(DATA_TYPE), public, pointer :: DATA => null()

! Set pointer
subroutine set_data(mode)
   integer, intent(in) :: mode
   select case (mode)
     case (1);     DATA => DATA_A
     case (2);     DATA => DATA_B
     case default; nullify(DATA)
   end select  
end subroutine set_data
```

Otherwise, if you don't change it that often, you could just use polymorphic allocation, that would be more elegant:

```
! Actual shared data
class(DATA_TYPE), allocatable :: DATA
```

And allocate the right type whenever needed:

```
! Polymorphic allocation
subroutine set_data(mode)
   integer, intent(in) :: mode
   integer :: ierr
   
   ! Deallocate first
   deallocate(DATA,stat=ierr) ! don't stop if not already allocated

   select case (mode)
     case (1);     allocate(DATA,source=DATA_A) 
     case (2);     allocate(DATA,source=DATA_B)
     case default; return
   end select  
end subroutine set_data
```

2. Should this be fixed (`parameter`ized) at compile time? Then, a compiler pre-processor will be most useful. For example, with the C pre-processor, you'd have:

```
#define DATATYPE_IS_A


#ifdef DATATYPE_IS_A
   type(DATA_TYPE_A), parameter :: DATA = [...]
#else
   type(DATA_TYPE_B), parameter :: DATA = [...]
#endif
```

This latter option is performed *before* compilation, i.e., that datatype is enforced and can never be changed.

Comment: Thank you for showing me these options and codes! Yes, for my case, it'll have to be able to change given user-defined parameters, after model compilation. Option 1 seems to be what I am looking for! Thank you. I'll try it out.

Comment: Well if changing user-defined parameters is all you have to do with it, maybe you don't even need two different datatypes, but rather two `parameter` variables of the same type

Comment: Two data types are necessary in this case due to legacy issue. One of the data type is used by a number of other modules that cannot be modified. But yes, I wish I could just merge them.